# phonegap CSS compatibility

Tags: css, cordova, compatibility

i'm currently trying to blur my android app via

```
-webkit-filter: blur(2px)
```

without success.

Is there an overview which CSS features are supported by phonegap? Are differences between platforms (Android, iOS)?

Thanks in advance,
J.W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no such overview. In the end, it depends on platforms webview capabilities. Not only there will be differences between android and iOS, but there will also be differences between various system versions. E.g. some css features will work on android 4.2 and some won't on android 2.3.7.. its just a webview. You need to test on as many devices as you can.